# Wordpress return preg_replace - content gone

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

i have put this function in the functions.php theme file:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
   return preg_replace('​/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

After that the whole pages content are gone, i have deleted that function from functions.php but the content still not showing, any ideas why?

Comment: have you cleared your caches?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work

Comment: you have a weird html number before your first `/ ` it is `&#8203;`

Comment: inspecting the html is `'&#8203;/&lt;p&gt;\s*(&lt;a .*&gt;)?\s*(&lt;img .* \/&gt;)\s*(&lt;\/a&gt;)?\s*&lt;\/p&gt;/iU' `

Comment: That code had to hide <p></p> tag for images, but its removed all tthe content who showed with the_content function. (In admin all pages content showing good)

Comment: I copy that code from this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-paragraph-tags-from-around-images/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: `<p>\s*(<a[^>]*>)?(<img[^>]+>)(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>`

It will also work with images within `<a>` tags.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/20hbO8/1/)

**Explained:**

```
<p>               # p tag
  \s*             # 0 or more spaces
  (<a[^>]*>)?     # optional <a> tag:   (first capturing group)
                  #  it matches <a and then any non '>' character
                  #  repeated 0 or more times and then a '>'
                  #  (second capturing group)
  (<img[^>]+>)    # image tag
  (<\/a>)?        # optional closing </a> (third capturing group)
  \s*
<\/p>
```